# React Native android - buttons are not responsive [new architecture]

Tags: android, react-native

I am trying to create a react native app that creates an android "draw over other apps" view.
I would like to add components in my react tsx to the view.

I am facing a few problems:

- When the view is attached to my react main view, the button is responsive, but when I switch to the floatview its not clickable
- It seems like the layout parameters are ignored when passing them in the styles so I have to set them in my native code.
- The close button from the float_view_layout.xml closes the view but I can't reopen it because react thinks that my view is still opened - isOpen is true so the state doesn't need any update and therefore no re-render.

When I debugged the app on android studio, I saw that the react button is added as a reactrootview with a child - ReactTextView

I have also tried using button from react-native-button

App.tsx

```
import * as React from 'react';

import { Button, StyleSheet, Text, View } from 'react-native';
import { FloatView } from 'float-native';

export default function App() {
  const [isOpen, setisOpen] = React.useState(false);

  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      <Button
        title="show"
        style={styles.btn}
        onPress={() => {
          setisOpen(true);
        }}
      />

      <FloatView
        isopen={isOpen}
        color="#2362b6"
        style={styles.box}
        rlwidth={800}
        rlheight={900}
      >
        {/* renders on the floatView */}
        <Text style={{ color: 'white' }}>FloatText</Text>
        <Button
          title="hide"
          style={styles.btn}
          onPress={() => {
            setisOpen(false);
          }}
        />
      </FloatView>

      {/* rendered by react */}
      <Button
        title="hide_out"
        style={styles.btn}
        onPress={() => {
          setisOpen(false);
        }}
      />
    </View>
  );
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    alignItems: 'center',
    justifyContent: 'center',
  },
  box: {
    position: 'relative',
    alignSelf: 'flex-end',
    flex: 1,
    backgroundColor: '#2362b6',
    width: 200,
    height: 600,
    backfaceVisibility: 'hidden',
  },
  btn: {
    backgroundColor: '#2362b6',
    color: 'white',
    borderBottomWidth: 1,
  },
});
```

android/src/main/java/com/floatnative/FloatViewManager.java

```
package com.floatnative;

import androidx.annotation.Nullable;
import android.content.Context;
import android.os.Build;
import android.util.Log;

import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.ViewParent;
import android.view.WindowManager;
import android.view.Gravity;

import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;
import android.graphics.PixelFormat;
import android.graphics.Color;

import com.facebook.react.module.annotations.ReactModule;
import com.facebook.react.uimanager.SimpleViewManager;
import com.facebook.react.uimanager.IViewGroupManager;
import com.facebook.react.uimanager.ThemedReactContext;
import com.facebook.react.uimanager.ViewManagerDelegate;
import com.facebook.react.uimanager.annotations.ReactProp;
import com.facebook.react.uimanager.annotations.ReactPropGroup;
import com.facebook.react.viewmanagers.FloatViewManagerDelegate;
import com.facebook.react.viewmanagers.FloatViewManagerInterface;
import com.facebook.soloader.SoLoader;
import com.facebook.react.bridge.ReactMethod;

@ReactModule(name = FloatViewManager.NAME)
public class FloatViewManager extends SimpleViewManager<FloatView> implements FloatViewManagerInterface<FloatView>,
        IViewGroupManager<FloatView> {

    public static final String NAME = "FloatView";
    private ThemedReactContext context;
    private FloatView floatView;
    private WindowManager.LayoutParams mParams;
    private boolean isAddedToWindowManager = false;
    private boolean isopen = false;

    private int rlHeight = 600;
    private int rlWidth = 400;

    static {
        if (BuildConfig.CODEGEN_MODULE_REGISTRATION != null) {
            SoLoader.loadLibrary(BuildConfig.CODEGEN_MODULE_REGISTRATION);
        }
    }

    private final ViewManagerDelegate<FloatView> mDelegate;

    public FloatViewManager() {
        mDelegate = new FloatViewManagerDelegate(this);
    }

    @Nullable
    @Override
    protected ViewManagerDelegate<FloatView> getDelegate() {
        return mDelegate;
    }

    @Override
    public String getName() {
        return NAME;
    }

    @Override
    public FloatView createViewInstance(ThemedReactContext context) {
        this.context = context;

        this.mParams = new WindowManager.LayoutParams(
                WindowManager.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                WindowManager.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_APPLICATION_OVERLAY,
                WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_FOCUSABLE,
                PixelFormat.TRANSLUCENT);

        mParams.gravity = Gravity.START;
        mParams.x = 0;
        mParams.y = 100;

        LayoutInflater layoutInflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

        View mView = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.float_view_layout, null);
        this.floatView = mView.findViewById(R.id.floatLayout);
        Button btn = mView.findViewById(R.id.button);
        btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                context.getCurrentActivity().runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        setIsopen(floatView, false);
                    }
                });
            }
        });
        mParams.gravity = Gravity.CENTER | Gravity.CENTER;

        return floatView;
    }

    @Override
    @ReactProp(name = "rlwidth", defaultInt = 600)
    public void setRlwidth(FloatView view, int width) {
        this.rlWidth = width;
        LinearLayout react_layout = ((LinearLayout) view.findViewById(R.id.reactLayout));
        LinearLayout.LayoutParams lp = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(width, rlHeight);
        react_layout.setLayoutParams(lp);

    floatView.invalidate();
    react_layout.invalidate();
    }

    @Override
    @ReactProp(name = "rlheight", defaultInt = 400)
    public void setRlheight(FloatView view, int height) {
        this.rlHeight = height;
        LinearLayout react_layout = ((LinearLayout) view.findViewById(R.id.reactLayout));
        LinearLayout.LayoutParams lp = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(rlWidth, height);
        react_layout.setLayoutParams(lp);

    floatView.invalidate();
    react_layout.invalidate();
    }

    @Override
    @ReactProp(name = "color")
    public void setColor(FloatView view, String color) {
        view.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor(color));
    }

    @Override
    @ReactProp(name = "isopen")
    public void setIsopen(FloatView view, boolean isopen) {
        Log.d("default", "setopen " + String.valueOf(isopen));
    this.isopen = isopen;
        if (isopen)
            open();
        else
            close();
    }

    @ReactMethod
    public void open() {
        Log.d("default", "open invoked");
        try {
            if (floatView != null && mParams != null && !isAddedToWindowManager) {
                if (floatView.getParent() instanceof ViewGroup) {
                    ((ViewGroup) floatView.getParent()).removeView(floatView);
                }
                ((WindowManager) context.getSystemService(Context.WINDOW_SERVICE)).addView(this.floatView, mParams);
                isAddedToWindowManager = true;

            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e("default", e.toString());
        }

    }

    @ReactMethod
    public void close() {
        Log.d("default", "close invoked");
        try {
            if (floatView != null && isAddedToWindowManager) {
                var parent = floatView.getParent();
                if (parent != null)
                    ((WindowManager) context.getSystemService(Context.WINDOW_SERVICE)).removeView(floatView);
                floatView.invalidate();
                isAddedToWindowManager = false;
                if (parent instanceof ViewGroup) {
                    ((ViewGroup) parent).removeAllViews();
                }
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e("default", e.toString());
        }
    }

    public void addView(FloatView parent, View child, int index) {
        Log.d("default", "addView at " + String.valueOf(index));
    child.setLayoutParams(new ViewGroup.LayoutParams(500, 100));

    ((LinearLayout) parent.findViewById(R.id.reactLayout)).addView(child, index);
    }

    public View getChildAt(FloatView parent, int index) {
        return ((LinearLayout) parent.findViewById(R.id.reactLayout)).getChildAt(index);
    }

    public void removeViewAt(FloatView parent, int index) {
        ((LinearLayout) parent.findViewById(R.id.reactLayout)).removeViewAt(index);
    }

    public int getChildCount(FloatView parent) {
        return ((LinearLayout) parent.findViewById(R.id.reactLayout)).getChildCount();
    }

    public boolean needsCustomLayoutForChildren() {
        return true;
    }
}
```

android\src\main\res\layout\float_view_layout.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:padding="4dp"
    android:background="@null"
>

    <com.floatnative.FloatView
        android:id="@+id/floatLayout"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:padding="10dp">

        <LinearLayout android:id="@+id/reactLayout"
            android:layout_width="600px"
            android:layout_height="400px"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:padding="10dp" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView"
            android:layout_width="289dp"
            android:layout_height="37dp"
            android:text="Hello, Float World" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="close" />
    </com.floatnative.FloatView>

</RelativeLayout>
```